# how to convert Object in array saving the key

Tags: javascript

I want to change my object into an Array of this objects, this is what I have:

```
const myObj = {
  element1: {
    value1: 1,
    value2: 2
  },
  element2: {
    value1: 3,
    value2: 4
  },
  element3: {
    value1: 5,
    value2: 6
  }
}
```

What I want to get is:

```
const myArray = [
  {element1: {
    value1: 1,
    value2: 2
  }
  },{
  element2: {
    value1: 3,
    value2: 4
  },{
  element3: {
    value1: 5,
    value2: 6
  }
 }
]
```

But I don't get it, this is my choice:

```
const myArray = Object.keys(myObj).map(item => myObj[item]);
```

But I lose the "elementX" key.

What are I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just forgetting to actually include the key, aka `item` variable, you just include the value of such key using `myObject[item]`.

Should be :

```
const myArray = Object.keys(myObject).map(item => {
  return { [item]: myObject[item] };
});
```

Since you forget the key, you just get the value.

Using implied returns from arrow functions with object literals, you can use an expression brackets like so: 
`Object.keys(myObject).map(item => ({ [item]: myObject[item] }) );`

Comment: I guess this would always return key as `item`, but not `element1`, `element2` etc

Comment: perfect! that was my problem, the only point is change item by [item], because if not all elements has "item" instead it value

Comment: Missing a closing bracket `}` on last line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, You have to return an object instead of just properties of an object

```
const myArray = Object.keys(myObj).map((item) => {
      let temp = {};
      temp[item] = myObj[item];
      return temp;
    });
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbvpes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)